# How to detect swipe completion in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android

Android has a [swipe container](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) view which I swipe with Appium to refresh a ListView. How can I use Appium to detect the completion of the swipe?

**edit**

Sorry, my question is not clear. I want a way for Appium to detect not when the swipe gesture is complete, but when the refresh animation is completed. Maybe I should ask a separate question.

Comment: If you know the last element name or text, after every wipe you can check the specific element name or text. I have faced same problem and I have managed by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had in past similar situation. So I've put all of my screen elements in PageObject design pattern. So after every swipe I just re-initialize screen, and by that logic all of its elements, and to be sure, I've checked if certain element is loaded on that screen, so in pseudocode would look like this:

```
public void checkSwipeScreen(){
    swipe(driver, DIRECTION.LEFT, 5);
    Screen screen = new Screen(driver);
    Assert.assertTrue(screen.elementIsLoaded(button), "Screen is not loaded properly");
}
```

so if all/one element is loaded on Your new screen, than swipe is successful.

With last parameter You control if swipe is longer or not (long duration).

And here is, if You like, swipe method:

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction) {
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

        case UP:
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

    }
}
```

and enum

```
public enum DIRECTION {
    DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

Hope this helps,